# Drupal 7 mod_rewrite enabled, still no clean urls

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have mode_rewrite enabled, but when I go to turn on clean url's, the page still simply refreshes to the 'test' screen. Is there a better way to test to be sure my mod-rewrite is enabled such taht drupal can use it?

I'm managing the server now on a cloud, so i'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `.htaccess` file, comment out line 62 `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and line 137 `</IfModule>`. This removes the conditional check for `mod_rewrite`. If you get a 500 server error when you visit your site after doing this then `mod_rewrite` is not enabled on the server.

That's a 'Drupal' way to do it I guess, but the best thing you can do is install the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and navigate to yoursite.com/?q=devel/phpinfo. Once there search the page for the text `mod_rewrite`. If it's missing, it's not installed.